# How to set up Load time weaving configuration without IDE?

Tags: java, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I want to change from AspectJ compile time weaving to Load time weaving. I cannot find detail setup instructions anywhere without IDE usage. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Use `javaagent` and `aop.xml` files. Everything you need is described in AspectJ's documentation
https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#enabling-load-time-weaving